# Conditional cell colour function not working inside the php tag

Tags: php

This is probably something stupid I've overlooked, but could someone please tell me why the following function does not work when I'm inside the php tag.
The function sets the background colour of a table cell based on a mysql value.

Function...

```
<?php
/* FUNCTION DEFINES GOLD SILVER BRONZE BLACK */
function get_color($cellcolor)
{
    $color = "#ffffff";
    if (($cellcolor <= 100) && ($cellcolor > 85)) {
        $color = "#C98910";
    } else if (($cellcolor <= 85) && ($cellcolor > 70)) {
        $color = "#A8A8A8";
    } else if (($cellcolor <= 70) && ($cellcolor > 55)) {
        $color = "#965A38";
    } else if ($cellcolor <= 55) {
        $color = "#000000";
    }
    return $color;
}
?>
```

My normal working usage is this...

Usage Snippet...

```
<?php do { ?>
<tr CLASS="data_left" >
<td bgcolor=<?php echo get_color($row_recordset1['rating']); ?>><span class="style1 count"></td>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row_recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordset1));  ?>
</table>
```

My problem is this.

How should I call my function from inside a PHP tag.
I have tried the following, but all the cells came out either red, pink, or green?

And they are not just the wrong colours being assigned, they have no relation to the values contained in $row[`rating`].

```
<?php
echo '
<tr class="data_center">
<td bgcolor="get_color(' . $row['rating'] . ')">' . $row['pos'] . '</td>
</tr>';
}
?>
```

Comment: What does the resulting HTML look like?

Comment: You could cut most of your conditions if u order your color ratings like this: http://pastebin.com/ePGST3Xk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this? You need to concatenate the return of the function to the string.

```
<?php
echo '
<tr class="data_center">
<td bgcolor="' . get_color($row['rating']) . '">' . $row['pos'] . '</td>
</tr>';
}
?>
```

I'm assuming that `$row['rating']` is returning a number less than or equal to 100.

Comment: Perfect. 
Such a fast response too. Thank you very much...

Yes you were correct, the retrieved value is between 0 and 100, or null.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while()` loop instead of a `do{}while()` loop. During the first run of the `do{}` statement, the variable `$row_recordset1` hasn't been declared yet because the first `while()` condition hasn't run yet.

Additionally, try using `style` with CSS instead of the `bgcolor` attribute.

This should work:

```
<?php while ($row_recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordset1)) {
    $color = get_color($row_recordset1['rating']); ?>
    <tr class="data_left">
    <td style="background-color:<?php echo $color; ?>;"><span class="style1 count"></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```